# CMake cannot find OpenMPI head file when I Install it by using conda

Tags: cmake, mpi, conda

I am not very familiar with installing package by conda. I install the OpenMPI by `conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 openmpi`. After that I write the following CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13 FATAL_ERROR)

project(CUDA_MPI LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)

add_library(Timer STATIC timer.h 
                         timer.cpp)
add_library(Coll STATIC  collectives.h 
                        collectives.cu)
add_executable(CUDA_MPI ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test.cpp)

include_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include)
target_link_libraries(CUDA_MPI PUBLIC Timer Coll MPI::MPI_CXX ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

My configuration log is as the following. It seems that CMake tool can find the library of OpenMPI but it cannot find the head file.

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 10.0.130
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/szhangcj/.conda/envs/distributed/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/szhangcj/.conda/envs/distributed/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -- works
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found version "10.0") 
-- Found MPI_CXX: /home/szhangcj/.conda/envs/distributed/lib/libmpi_cxx.so (found version "3.1") 
-- Found MPI: TRUE (found version "3.1")  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/szhangcj/HPC/MPI/baidu-allreduce/build
```

The error message from the generating stage is as the following.

```
Scanning dependencies of target Timer
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Timer.dir/timer.cpp.o
[ 28%] Linking CXX static library libTimer.a
[ 28%] Built target Timer
Scanning dependencies of target Coll
[ 42%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/Coll.dir/collectives.cu.o
/home/szhangcj/HPC/MPI/baidu-allreduce/collectives.cu:9:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mpi.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/Coll.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Coll.dir/collectives.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Coll.dir/collectives.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:147: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Coll.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Coll.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have checked the installation directory and I found that there is no include directory under the openmpi folder. How can I fix this?

What's more, on another machine, I repeat the same process to install the Openmpi by using conda. After that, I even cannot find the MPI library.

Comment: "It seems that CMake tool can find the library of OpenMPI but it cannot find the head file." - I see no evidence of the missed header file in the configuration log. Probably, you get some error message when build the project? Please, show that error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The configure stage does not give me any error.

Comment: So you want to use MPI from CUDA. I don't know how they cooperate, but exactly their cooperation seems to be your real problem. Note, that `MPI::MPI_CXX` is MPI target for C++ compiler, not sure whether it is intended to work for CUDA compiler. Sidenote: Why do you use `find_package(CUDA)` if you already add CUDA to the `LANGUAGES` list of `project()` call?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Because I can use the CUDA aware MPI to do the distributed computation. I think this is not the problem. Actually, I can include the mpi path manually and everything works well.